# How to initialize interface in Activity.

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface

I need to call a method in fragment when a certain item is selected in navigation drawer activity. 
For this, I've created one interface which I Will be initializing & calling a method from the activity, Also I'll implement this interface in Fragment and override this method.
Here is code snippet for declaring an interface.

```
public interface AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges {
     void alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges(int navigationItemID);
}
```

And this is how I'm initializing in activity.

```
    private AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges = (AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges) this;
    }
```

Here I'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException` for initializing it.
Not sure what I'm missing here or what's wrong.

Comment: Just implement your interface by `implements AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges`

Comment: Why ? I do not want to implement in the same activity, I want to implement this interface in It's on of the container fragments.

Comment: So just do it in fragment. What is the problem ?

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.ClassCastException for initializing it in Activity.

Comment: check my answer @MihirPatel it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you have to implements this interface to your activity/fragment for eg :

MainActivity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentClassName.AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges{

//override methods

@Override
    public void alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges(String navigationItemID) {
// now use navigationItemID here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not something I'm looking for. I do not want to implement in the same activity. I want to implement in its container fragment. Here is how I achieved it. `(new DefaultProfileFragment()).alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges();`

Comment: i already mentioned it u can implement in activity as well in fragment class

Answer (score 0):

Step-1

```
public interface AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges {

     void alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges(int navigationItemID);
}
```

define this method from which activity and class you want transfer your data

Step 2 -

Define this method also in step 1 class.

```
private  AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges favListner;

public void setAlertOnDiscardListner(AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges 
                                favOnTouchListner) {

        favListner = favOnTouchListner;
    }
```

Step -3 .

pass value from Step 1 class like below

```
favListner.alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges(int navigationItemID);
```

Step-4 
In which class you want data first implement that interface like.

```
Class A implements YourActivity_where_interface define.AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges{

override Method.
}
```

Step 5.

You Should have to do one thing also in that class where you want data .

You should have to initialise interface from on Create method like below.

YourActivity_where_interface define.`setAlertOnDiscardListner(this);`

Done now you can play with it.

Comment: this seems quite a lengthy process, I achieved in a single line.               `(new DefaultProfileFragment()).alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChang‌​es();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved it,
I called a method through an object of a fragment in which I wanted to implement a method.

Fragment Class -

```
 public class DefaultProfileFragment extends Fragment implements 
 AlertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges {
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default_profile, container, 
    false);
    mContext = view.getContext();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChanges(int navigationItemID) {
    showDismissWarning(navigationItemID);
}
```

Activity from which I need to call interface method.
A Just simple object of a fragment class and name of a method. Nothing fancy needs to be done. No need to initialize an interface.

```
(new DefaultProfileFragment()).alertForDiscardDefaultProfileChang‌​‌​es(id);
```